# How to clone value in angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a edit form with save and cancel button. When the save will be clicked, the value will be send to server and everything is okey.

But in case server did not able to process the data, I need come back to the revious state of the data.

So is there a way to clone the data and keep it, in case of server error, send it to the UI form for display?

Comment: Don't navigate away until you get a successful server response. That is the best I (*or probably anyone*) can do for you unless you decide to grace this question with actual code.

Comment: Yes there is. For a more specific answer please write a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign` to create a copy of an object:

```
    // Clone the object to retain a copy
    this.originalProduct = Object.assign({}, value);
```

The first argument is the target object, which in this example is an empty object. The second argument is the source object, which in this example is the object to copy. So this basically creates a new object and copies all of the property values from the original one into them.

That results in a copy of the object.

However, note that it won't do deep cloning. See the docs for more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign